# Highcharts. Heat Map. Half empty cell

Tags: highcharts

how can I have a cell in a heat map not completely full?

Example: https://www.anonimg.com/img/0645c7ec9595d971f285c69513e343bd.png

Comment: It's not supported. You can try to use columnrange series instead.

Comment: could I do something to give a difference to a cell? like.. using 2 colors, cross it...

Comment: You can use gradient color for specific point.

Comment: That wouldnt be very clear, I would like to express a small difference in some points, but keeping their "main colour"

Comment: You know that gradient's doesn't have to be really gradient? But have two colors instead, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4rTBY/524/

Comment: oh, I dont really get it, because I am already using the gradient for the heat map, and it only generates one color, the one related to the value http://jsfiddle.net/22y7m8x4/

Comment: Why you have y1 = y2? It should be different value, right? See: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/1/

Comment: You are right, so, this is what I have, http://jsfiddle.net/vtrbkd1v/ It shows 2 colours, what I would like to show is: Main color the color related to the value, like in the normal heat map, and a second color in the top of the cell, a brown for example. I also would like to be able to set how much space each one should fill. So I have got kind of mess :)

Comment: As I said before, heatmap = one color per cell. Use column range and manage points manually, or use gradient color for cells like in my previous example.

Comment: I am lost, does that mean I can not mix my heat map with it? like your http://jsfiddle.net/4rTBY/524/ but instead of '#003399', having the "colour related to the heat map"?  If the answer its no, could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you can't mix color from `colorAxis` with customized gradient.

Comment: Understood, so gradient color for cells its not a solution for this case, could you give me an example of how could it be done with column range in a heat map or to look like a heat map? (I need its colorAxis)

Comment: `colorAxis` is supported only by Highmaps (including heatmap), not by Highcharts, so you can't use column range again, sorry.

Comment: So, are saying now that its impossible to do what I need?

Comment: It was in my first comment under your question, you know that? ;) It's not supported. Or just resign from `colorAxis` and use gradients.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59939/discussion-between-pedro4441-and-pawel-fus).